# Different execution times while executing FORALL .. INSERT INTO .. VALUES

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql, database-performance, bulkinsert

We are experiencing different execution times of a `FORALL .. INSERT INTO .. VALUES` statement. We created a test which simulates the behaviour. Running the script below shows execution times between 0.5 and 7-8 seconds randomly distributed.

The script is executed on a client running SQL Developer and the Oracle DB is running on a HyperV Server VM on the same network. On this VM the assigned Memory and Hard Disk size look sufficient.

What could be the reason of the different execution times, and what do we have for possibilities to stabilize (and minimize of course) the execution times?

**EDIT: The relevant performance is ONLY the time the FORALL .. INSERT statement needs - clearly meassured in the script with the DBMS.PUT_LINE commands. The performance for creating the test data is irrelevant for my question!**

Here is the test script:

```
DECLARE
  SUBTYPE t_logmsg_rec IS logmsg%ROWTYPE;
  TYPE t_logmsg_list IS TABLE OF t_logmsg_rec;
  l_logmsg_list t_logmsg_list := t_logmsg_list();
  l_logmsg_rec t_logmsg_rec;
  l_max_logmsg_key_id logmsg.KEY_ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT NVL(MAX(KEY_ID),1)
    INTO l_max_logmsg_key_id
    FROM logmsg;

  FOR i IN 1..10000 LOOP
    l_max_logmsg_key_id := l_max_logmsg_key_id + 1;
    l_logmsg_rec.key_id        := l_max_logmsg_key_id;
    l_logmsg_rec.msg_id        := 1;
    l_logmsg_rec.session_id    := 666;
    l_logmsg_rec.log_timestamp := current_timestamp;
    l_logmsg_rec.log_pck       := 'perf_test';
    l_logmsg_rec.log_user      := 'fl';
    l_logmsg_rec.log_type      := 1;
    l_logmsg_rec.log_msg       := 'test msg ' ||i;

    l_logmsg_rec.log_apl       := 1;

    l_logmsg_list.EXTEND;
    l_logmsg_list(l_logmsg_list.COUNT) := l_logmsg_rec;
  END LOOP;

  dbms_output.put_line('Start: ' || current_timestamp);

  FORALL l_idx IN 1 .. l_logmsg_list.COUNT
      INSERT INTO logmsg VALUES l_logmsg_list (l_idx);

  dbms_output.put_line('End: ' || current_timestamp);
END;
/
```

And the table creation script:

```
CREATE TABLE "SCOTT"."LOGMSG" 
(   "KEY_ID" NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"MSG_ID" NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"LOG_TYPE" NUMBER(3,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"LOG_TIMESTAMP" TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"LOG_USER" VARCHAR2(32 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"LOG_MSG" VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE), 
"LOG_APL" NUMBER(5,0), 
"LOG_ATT" "SYS"."XMLTYPE" , 
"LOG_PCK" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"SESSION_ID" NUMBER(38,0), 
 CONSTRAINT "PK_LOGMSG" PRIMARY KEY ("KEY_ID")
USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
STORAGE(INITIAL 81920 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "SCOTT_I_TABLESPACE"  ENABLE
) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
PCTFREE 0 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
STORAGE(INITIAL 81920 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "SCOTT_TABLESPACE" 
XMLTYPE COLUMN "LOG_ATT" STORE AS BASICFILE CLOB (
TABLESPACE "SCOTT_TABLESPACE" DISABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 16384 RETENTION 
NOCACHE LOGGING 
STORAGE(INITIAL 81920 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)) ;

CREATE INDEX "SCOTT"."IX_LOGMSG_1" ON "SCOTT"."LOGMSG" ("MSG_ID") 
PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
STORAGE(INITIAL 81920 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "SCOTT_I_TABLESPACE" ;

CREATE INDEX "SCOTT"."IX_LOGMSG_2" ON "SCOTT"."LOGMSG" ("SESSION_ID") 
PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
STORAGE(INITIAL 81920 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "SCOTT_I_TABLESPACE" ;

CREATE INDEX "SCOTT"."IX_LOGMSG_3" ON "SCOTT"."LOGMSG" ("LOG_TIMESTAMP") 
PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
STORAGE(INITIAL 81920 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "SCOTT_I_TABLESPACE" ;

CREATE INDEX "SCOTT"."IX_LOGMSG_C1" ON "SCOTT"."LOGMSG" ("LOG_MSG") 
PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "SCOTT_I_TABLESPACE" ;

CREATE INDEX "SCOTT"."IX_LOGMSG_C2" ON "SCOTT"."LOGMSG" ("LOG_PCK") 
PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "SCOTT_I_TABLESPACE" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You can try a alternative where you can avoid the row by row population in the array. I have tried to illustrate the same example with a single Bulk Collect operation. Hope  it helps.

```
set sqlbl on;
DECLARE
  TYPE t_logmsg_tab IS TABLE OF log_msg%ROWTYPE;
  lv_log_msg t_logmsg_tab;
BEGIN


--Since i can see only 10000 values are fetched so here we need not to use LIMIT clause but if
--date volume is more then we need to put LIMIT clause to prevent memory overflow

  SELECT NVL(MAX(KEY_ID) OVER(ORDER BY 1),1)+LEVEL,
         '1'  msg_id,
         '666' session_id,
         current_timestamp,
         'perf_test' log_pck,
         'f1' log_user,
         1 log_type,
         'test msg '||LEVEL,
         '1' log_apl
         BULK COLLECT INTO 
         lv_log_msg
        FROM l_max_logmsg_key_id
        CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10001;

--Not required going for row by row processing will definitely take toll
--So avoiding and performing a bulk Collect Operation


--  SELECT NVL(MAX(KEY_ID),1)
--    INTO l_max_logmsg_key_id
--    FROM logmsg;
--
--  FOR i IN 1..10000 LOOP
--    l_max_logmsg_key_id := l_max_logmsg_key_id + 1;
--    l_logmsg_rec.key_id        := l_max_logmsg_key_id;
--    l_logmsg_rec.msg_id        := 1;
--    l_logmsg_rec.session_id    := 666;
--    l_logmsg_rec.log_timestamp := current_timestamp;
--    l_logmsg_rec.log_pck       := 'perf_test';
--    l_logmsg_rec.log_user      := 'fl';
--    l_logmsg_rec.log_type      := 1;
--    l_logmsg_rec.log_msg       := 'test msg ' ||i;
--
--    l_logmsg_rec.log_apl       := 1;
--
--    l_logmsg_list.EXTEND;
--    l_logmsg_list(l_logmsg_list.COUNT) := l_logmsg_rec;
--  END LOOP;

  IF lv_log_msg.EXISTS(1) THEN

  dbms_output.put_line('Start: ' || current_timestamp);

  FORALL l_idx IN lv_log_msg.FIRST .. lv_log_msg.LAST
      INSERT INTO logmsg VALUES lv_log_msg (l_idx);

  dbms_output.put_line('End: ' || current_timestamp);

  END IF;

END;
/
```

Comment: Please check my EDIT comment.